# Table state in extendedDataTable is not saving after removing some columns

Tags: java, jsf-2

I am developing a web based application.
I am facing one problem with table state saving technique.
I have given these parameters in extendedDataTable.

```
<rich:extendedDataTable id="tblUsrSearchResults" var="rr"
       height="200px" enableContextMenu="true"
       tableState="#{userSearchController.edtUsrSrchRsltsTblState}"
       selection="#{userSearchController.edtUsrSrchRsltsSelection}"
       value="#{userSearchController.usrSearchResults}" rowKeyVar="idx">
```

I am trying to hide one of the column temporarily from all listed by unchecking it as follows - [image]

If I am unchecking it, then it is hiding that column but at the same time also not displaying data (All the rows becomes hidden).
I want data(all rows) to remain displayed, so that I can save the table state as follows - [image]

or In short I want to save table state after hiding one of the columns like described above and should be able to display it back some other point of time.
(Currently I can save the table state but only if the column width is changing)
Please help me in solving this problem.